# Java Firebase Admin SDK setValue Never Completes

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to make a mod for Minecraft 1.8.9 (using Forge), and I need to use Firebase as a part of the project. I've gotten Forge setup and Firebase is working as a dependency. The mod builds, and I'm able to use the mod in-game. For those curious, here's my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            name "forge"
            url "https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven"
        }
        maven {
            name "google"
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.1-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle.forge'

allprojects {
  repositories {
    // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
    mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
  }
}

version = "1.0a"
group= "com.oshotz.testmod" // http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html
archivesBaseName = "testmod"

minecraft {
    version = "1.8.9-11.15.1.2318-1.8.9"
    runDir = "run"
    
    mappings = "stable_20"
}

configurations {
    shade
    implementation.extendsFrom shade
}

dependencies {
    shade 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.2.0'
    shade 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0'
}

jar {
    configurations.shade.each { dep ->
        from(project.zipTree(dep)){
            exclude 'META-INF', 'META-INF/**'
        }
    }
}

processResources
{
    // this will ensure that this task is redone when the versions change.
    inputs.property "version", project.version
    inputs.property "mcversion", project.minecraft.version

    // replace stuff in mcmod.info, nothing else
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        include 'mcmod.info'
                
        // replace version and mcversion
        expand 'version':project.version, 'mcversion':project.minecraft.version
    }
        
    // copy everything else, thats not the mcmod.info
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        exclude 'mcmod.info'
    }
}
```

Again, as I mentioned, this works. Here's my main mod file:

```java
package com.oshotz.testmod;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import com.google.api.core.ApiFuture;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;

// import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.storage.v2.Object;

import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
// import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPostInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;
import scala.collection.parallel.Tasks;

// import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;

@Mod(modid = Reference.MOD_ID, name = Reference.MOD_NAME, version = Reference.VERSION)
public class TestMod {
  
  // private Minecraft mc = Minecraft.getMinecraft();
  private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;

  @EventHandler
  public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event) {
    
  }

  @EventHandler
  public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {

    System.out.println("Test Mod is running!");

    FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Brandon\\credentials.json");

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
      .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
      .setDatabaseUrl("https://<redacted>.firebaseio.com")
      .build();

    FirebaseApp defaultApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://<redacted>.firebaseio.com");

    System.out.println(defaultApp.getName());

    DatabaseReference ref = firebaseDatabase.getReference("message");
    ref.setValue("Hello, World!", null);

    ref.setValue("testing!!", new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
      @Override
      public void onComplete(DatabaseError de, DatabaseReference dr) {
        System.out.println("finish");
      }
    });

    ChatEventHandler chatEventHandler = new ChatEventHandler();
    MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(chatEventHandler);

    ClientTickEventHandler clientTickEventHandler = new ClientTickEventHandler();
    MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(clientTickEventHandler);

    ChestEventHandler chestEventHandler = new ChestEventHandler();
    MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(chestEventHandler);

    // update("hello world");
    
  }

  @EventHandler
  public void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent event) {
    
  }

  public void update(String value) {
    update(value, "message");
  }

  public void update(String value, String key) {
      try {
          DatabaseReference ref = firebaseDatabase.getReference(key);
          final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
          ref.setValue(value, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
              @Override
              public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                  if (databaseError != null) {
                      System.out.println("Data could not be saved " + databaseError.getMessage());
                      latch.countDown();
                  } else {
                      System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
                      latch.countDown();
                  }
              }
          });
          latch.await();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
  
}
```

...note that I've commented out the call to the `update` function, which I'll explain in a moment.

The code, as is above, builds and runs. I can use the mod in game. However, even though `"Test Mod is running!"` and `[DEFAULT]` (printed by the `System.out.println(defaultApp.getName());` line) are both printed to the console (meaning the mod was properly loaded, and the Firebase dependency is working), neither of the two calls to `setValue` do ***anything***. Nothing else is printed, and the data in the Realtime Database is not changed or updated.

If I uncomment the `update("hello world");` line, then it calls the `update` function, which implements a `CountDownLatch`, as suggested by many of the other answers I've found on this issue. However, when running the game, it hangs indefinitely on the `update("hello world");` line, until I force quit the game. Again, the data stored in Firebase is not changed or updated (for reference, I've created the `"message"` ref manually in Firebase, so the database is not completely empty).

No errors are thrown anywhere. Looking at the database rule monitoring, it seems as though the database never actually receives the requests at all (the database has no allows, denies, or errors reported).

I have no idea why this is, and any help would be appreciated. If I need to include any other files, let me know!

Also: I'm using the Java 1.8 JDK (Java 8) for Windows x64, and am using Gradle 4.0 (as Forge for 1.8.9 doesn't play nicely with newer versions).

Comment: Have you tried to check if there is an error when you're using setValue?

Comment: @AlexMamo there's no errors being printed to the console, no

Comment: Can show us how did you do that?

Comment: @AlexMamo see the main mod file code; it's not printing any errors. As a side note, I ended up trying MongoDB Atlas, and I got it working without issue. I'll probably just stick with it, even though I'm much more familiar with Firebase.